# Have to click twice to get number, Java program not working as intended

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, calculator

I have a question regarding a calculator I'm coding in Java, as you will see in the code, I created a method which is `buttonOnScreen()` that when a button is clicked it creates a new label instance, adds the text on the button to it and adds it to the FlowPane, but my problem now I have to click any button twice to get a number on the FlowPane.

```
package calculator;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;



public class Gui extends Application {



//over here all gui initilisation
private Stage Window;

private Scene scene1;

private GridPane operationsgrid;
private BorderPane borderpane;
private FlowPane screen;

private Button add;
private Button subtract;
private Button multiply;
private Button divide;
private Button button1, button2, button3, button4, button5, button6, button7, button8, button9, button0, buttonequals, buttondot;



@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {


    Window = primaryStage;
    Window.setTitle("HackCalc");
    //BUTTONS
    button0 = new Button("0");
    button0.setStyle("-fx-font: 30 arial; -fx-base: #b6e7c9;");
    button1 = new Button("1");
    button1.setStyle("-fx-font: 30 arial; -fx-base: #b6e7c9;");
    button2 = new Button("2");
    button2.setStyle("-fx-font: 30 arial; -fx-base: #b6e7c9;");
    button3 = new Button("3");
    button3.setStyle("-fx-font: 30 arial; -fx-base: #b6e7c9;");
    button4 = new Button("4");
    button4.setStyle("-fx-font: 30 arial; -fx-base: #b6e7c9;");
    button5 = new Button("5");
    button5.setStyle("-fx-font: 30 arial; -fx-base: #b6e7c9;");
    button6 = new Button("6");
    button6.setStyle("-fx-font: 30 arial; -fx-base: #b6e7c9;");
    button7 = new Button("7");
    button7.setStyle("-fx-font: 30 arial; -fx-base: #b6e7c9;");
    button8 = new Button("8");
    button8.setStyle("-fx-font: 30 arial; -fx-base: #b6e7c9;");
    button9 = new Button("9");
    button9.setStyle("-fx-font: 30 arial; -fx-base: #b6e7c9;");
    buttonequals = new Button("=");
    buttonequals.setStyle("-fx-font: 30 arial; -fx-base: #b6e7c9;");
    buttondot = new Button(".");
    buttondot.setStyle("-fx-font: 33 arial; -fx-base: #b6e7c9;");
    buttondot.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    add = new Button("+");
    add.setStyle("-fx-font: 30 arial");
    subtract = new Button("-");
    subtract.setStyle("-fx-font: 33 arial");
    multiply = new Button("x");
    multiply.setStyle("-fx-font: 30 arial");
    divide = new Button("÷");
    divide.setStyle("-fx-font: 30 arial");

    //OPERATIONS GRID
    operationsgrid = new GridPane();
    operationsgrid.setPrefSize(300, 300);
    operationsgrid.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    operationsgrid.setVgap(8);
    operationsgrid.setHgap(10);
    operationsgrid.setPadding(new Insets(0, 0, 10, 0));
    GridPane.setConstraints(button1, 0, 0);
    GridPane.setConstraints(button2, 1, 0);
    GridPane.setConstraints(button3, 2, 0);
    GridPane.setConstraints(button4, 0, 1);
    GridPane.setConstraints(button5, 1, 1);
    GridPane.setConstraints(button6, 2, 1);
    GridPane.setConstraints(button7, 0, 2);
    GridPane.setConstraints(button8, 1, 2);
    GridPane.setConstraints(button9, 2, 2);
    GridPane.setConstraints(button0, 0, 3);
    GridPane.setConstraints(buttonequals, 2, 3);
    GridPane.setConstraints(buttondot, 1, 3);
    GridPane.setConstraints(add, 0, 4);
    GridPane.setConstraints(subtract, 1, 4);
    GridPane.setConstraints(multiply, 2, 4);
    GridPane.setConstraints(divide, 1, 5);
    operationsgrid.getChildren().addAll(button0, button1, button2, button3, button4, button5, button6, button7, button8, button9, buttonequals, buttondot, add, subtract, multiply, divide);

    //SCREEN FLOWPANE
    screen = new FlowPane();
    screen.setPadding(new Insets(35, 10, 10, 10));
    screen.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_CENTER);

    borderpane = new BorderPane();
    borderpane.setBottom(operationsgrid);
    borderpane.setTop(screen);


    scene1 = new Scene(borderpane, 400, 500);

    Window.setScene(scene1);

    Window.show();



    //over here all input handling
    add.setOnAction(event -> System.out.println("+"));
    subtract.setOnAction(event -> System.out.println("-"));
    multiply.setOnAction(event -> System.out.println("x"));
    divide.setOnAction(event -> buttonOnScreen(divide));
    button0.setOnAction(event -> buttonOnScreen(button0));

}
private void buttonOnScreen(Button button){
    Button b;
    b = button;
    b.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            Label label = new Label(b.getText());
            screen.getChildren().add(label);
            label.setStyle("-fx-font: 40 arial");

        }
    });

    }

}
```

In the code, I used the method with Button0 and divide, but I have to click them twice to get them on the screen, help is much appreciated.

Also, please if you have comments on my code on making it cleaner or anything like that, please do :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding action event handler inside an action event handler. Do this instead:

```
divide.setOnAction(event -> buttonOnScreen(divide));

private void buttonOnScreen(final Button button) {
    Label label = new Label(button.getText());
    screen.getChildren().add(label);
    label.setStyle("-fx-font: 40 arial");
}
```

Secondly, I think it would be neater to just declare a single `Label`, and then append the text in - just my suggestion though.

### Edit

To illustrate what single `Label` means...

```
private Label screenLabel;
this.screenLabel = new Label();
this.screenLabel.setStyle("-fx-font: 40 arial");


private void buttonOnScreen(final Button button) {
    String text = this.screenText.getText();
    text += button.getText();

    this.screenLabel.setText(text);
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks that was awesome :), and if it isn't too much, would you please write code explaining to me what you mean about a single label? I am still a beginner in programming terminology.